# Check pressed space then add diez tag using jquery with multi language

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex, mobile

I am trying to add Diez tag `#` after the pressed space using jquery when user type. I have created this **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/RZwrzQ)** from codepen.io.

In this demo when you write for example (`how are you`) the javascript code will change it like this (`#how #are #you`).

I am checking the words for adding #(diez) tag with `function addHashtags(text) { ... }` this function.

1-) So normally it is working fine for English characters. But I want to do it multiple language. Now the problem is when I type Turkish characters like (`üğşıöç`). So what happened when I write with the Turkish characters word. You can test it with this word. When I write (`üzüm`) or (`hüseyin`) javascript should change this words like (`#üzüm #hüseyin`) but it is not. It is adding like this (`#ü#zü#m #hü#seyin` ).[image] (Solved)

2-) Another problem is some other language. Javascript not adding #(diez) tag when user type Arabic, Azerbaijan, Japanese.. etc. Nothing happened when I write like (`私は家族と一緒に行きます`) or (`ผมไปกับครอบครัวของฉัน`)etc. This is a big problem for me. I need a solution. [image](Solved)

3-) If you check **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/RZwrzQ)** you can see I have used `textInput`. It isn't work in `Firefox` but working on mobile devices. So if I use `keypress` the codes are working on `FireFox` but not working on mobile. My code should be work with all devices. [image] (Solved)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.mobilecheck = function() {
      var check = false;
      (function(a) {
         if (
            /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(
               a
            ) ||
            /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(
               a.substr(0, 4)
            )
         )
            check = true;
      })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
      return check;
   };
   // Move cursor to the end.
   function placeCaretAtEndX(el) {
      el.focus();
      if (
         typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" &&
         typeof document.createRange != "undefined"
      ) {
         var range = document.createRange();
         range.selectNodeContents(el);
         range.collapse(false);
         var sel = window.getSelection();
         sel.removeAllRanges();
         sel.addRange(range);
      } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
         var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
         textRange.moveToElementText(el);
         textRange.collapse(false);
         textRange.select();
      }
   }

   // Define special characters:
   var charactersX = [
      0,
      32, // space
      13 // enter
      // add other punctuation symbols or keys
   ];

   // Convert characters to charCode
   function toCharCodeX(char) {
      return char.charCodeAt(0);
   }

   var forbiddenCharactersX = [
      toCharCodeX("_"),
      toCharCodeX("-"),
      toCharCodeX("?"),
      toCharCodeX("*"),
      toCharCodeX("\\"),
      toCharCodeX("/"),
      toCharCodeX("("),
      toCharCodeX(")"),
      toCharCodeX("="),
      toCharCodeX("&"),
      toCharCodeX("%"),
      toCharCodeX("+"),
      toCharCodeX("^"),
      toCharCodeX("#"),
      toCharCodeX("'"),
      toCharCodeX("<"),
      toCharCodeX("|"),
      toCharCodeX(">"),
      toCharCodeX("."),
      toCharCodeX(","),
      toCharCodeX(";")
   ];

   $(document).on("textInput", "#text", function(event) {
      var code = event.which; window.mobilecheck() ? event.originalEvent.data.charCodeAt(0) : event.which;
      if (charactersX.indexOf(code) > -1) {
         // Get and modify text.
         var text = $("#text").text();
         text = XRegExp.replaceEach(text, [
            [/#\s*/g, ""],
            [/\s{2,}/g, " "],
            [XRegExp("(?:\\s|^)([\\p{L}\\p{N}]+)(?=\\s|$)(?=.*\\s\\1(?=\\s|$))","gi"),""],
            [XRegExp("([\\p{N}\\p{L}]+)", "g"), "#$1"]
         ]);
         // Save content.
         $("#text").text(text);
         // Move cursor to the end
         placeCaretAtEndX(document.querySelector("#text"));
      } else if (forbiddenCharactersX.has(code)) {
         event.preventDefault();
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.container {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:600px;
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:10px;
   margin:0px auto;
   margin-top:50px;
}
* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.addiez {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:30px;
   border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
   outline:none;
   text-transform: lowercase;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.addiez::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
   color: rgb(0, 0, 1);
}
.addiez[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before  {
      content:attr(placeholder);
      color: #444;
    }

.note {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:30px;
   font-weight:300;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   line-height:1.8rem;
   font-size:13px;
}
.ad_text {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:10px 30px;
   overflow:hidden;
   font-weight:300;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   line-height:1.8rem;
   font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp@3.2.0/xregexp-all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="addiez" contenteditable="true" id="text" placeholder="Write something with space"></div>
   <div class="ad_text" id="ad_text"></div>
```

Comment: Why would a space or enter trigger it? Wouldn't you only fire it once they're done typing?

Comment: @Waxi Thanks for your comment. I just want to show it user. Whic text added `#` in his word.

Comment: @DevStud Check out my *updated* answer that fits your requirements.

Comment: @DevStud, have you seen my answer below? It is downvoted to -2 for some reason. It is working very well. Actually, it is the only answer working. But you haven't commented at all.

Comment: What is the bounty for? What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @revo old answer is not working. If you check in question you can see 1 and 2 for what i am looking for.

Comment: @revo the bouthy for fixed all problems. Please look at in question number 1 and 2.

Comment: Please [check this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvgqPJ).

Comment: @revo It looks like you used [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) nice answer and solution with short code. Thank you. Now all language is working fine.

Comment: I wanted to work on this but when I run your snippet, it doesn't put anything on the words. Is it because I use IE11 ?

Comment: **Any closer to this working?** When I run your snippet and type words and spaces, nothing happens to the words or spaces. Is something supposed to happen ? Or, how does someone use it ? I'm using IE11.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript Regular Expressions are not Unicode-aware, at least talking ES5. To be able to use Unicode literals you have to work with `\u` (Unicode escape sequences) or libraries like XRegExp that bring support for Unicode properties.

By importing XRegExp to your project, you are able to translate old Regular Expressions to new Unicode-aware patterns. Unicode properties are then available to be used in standard `\p{L}` or single-letter `\pL` notation.

I modified your code a little bit to bring such a feature alive:

```
text = XRegExp.replaceEach(text, [
            [/#\s*/g, ""],
            [/\s{2,}/g, " "],
            [XRegExp(`(?:\\s|^)([\\p{L}\\p{N}]+)(?=\\s|$)(?=.*\\s\\1(?=\\s|$))`, "gi"), ""],
            [XRegExp(`([\\p{N}\\p{L}]+)`, "g"), "#$1"]
         ]);
```

First two regexes are easy to understand (you had them before) but third seems to be pell-mell but if you be more precise about it you'll find that `(?:\\s|^)` and `(?=\\s|$)` both corresponds to `\b` and since `\b` uses ASCII-only interpretations of *word boundary* I had to work it out like that.

[Live demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvgqPJ)

**Breakdown**:

- `\p{L}` any kind of letter from any language.
- `\p{N}` any kind of
  numeric character in any script.

More about >[Unicode categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)<.

Comment: it is not working on Firefox and Safari OS X browsers.

Comment: safari browser say SyntaxError: Invalid character: '`' on line 69 from your [Live demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvgqPJ)

Comment: also safari said ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set on line 36 in your [Live demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvgqPJ)

Comment: XRegExp supports major browsers as stated *Internet Explorer 5.5+, Firefox 1.5+, Chrome, Safari 3+, and Opera 11+*. The problem lies within your code. Check demo again. @DevStud

Comment: It works in firefox now without problem. But not working on safari.

Comment: I don't have Safari installed so I can't run a debugger unfortunately. Check if Safari console knows `XRegExp` object by typing the same in it. If script is imported successfully you can try to play with it and check if lib works. If it does you surely should review your own code afterward. @DevStud

Comment: @rove I have checked your updated code you changed `var code = event.originalEvent.data.charCodeAt(0);` to  `var code = event.which;` I used `charCodeAt(0)` because `event.which` not working on mobile browsers. Now your code is working on desktop pc but not working on mobile browsers

Comment: @rove Safari console not talking about any XRegExp problem it says just problem is on line `var charactersX = new Set([ .... ]);`

Comment: For Safari issue see [this topic](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/1967). For mobile browsers I didn't find a straight forward solution but applied a workaround. Check demo now. @DevStud

Comment: your new Live demo working on the desktop not working mobile browsers. I want to say thank you very much for your effort Dear.

Comment: can you check sln answer it looks like work without XRegExp

Comment: Your problem for now is not XRegExp but only how to get key code from user (being compatible for both mobile and desktop). sln provided a set of ranges / characters for `\p{L}` and `\p{N}` to avoid using XRegExp lib. It's good but doesn't solve the problem we are dealing with right now. @DevStud

Comment: @rove you are right dear. I am still searching for a solution for your answer. But i can't.

Comment: I think normaly your code is working fine but the problem is `Set`. I found something here [MDN for Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility) It looks like `Set` is not support mobile browsers.

Comment: if i use `keypress` it is working desktop `firefox` but not working on mobile phones. But if i use `textInput` it is working mobile devices not working `firefox`.

Comment: I confirm it works on Chrome and Firefox (latest versions). @DevStud

Comment: @ravo sorry i see it is working but not working on mobile devices.

Comment: I'd encourage you to post a question on SO stating key code problem. @DevStud

Comment: can you check this for a solution [Solutiom](https://icewalker2g.wordpress.com/2016/08/31/determining-event-keycode-on-mobile-browser-chrome-android-firefox/)

Comment: I [merged two snippets](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXEGym). Give your feedback. @DevStud

Comment: Then please open a new question for it right now. @DevStud

Comment: what should be question title. There are so many key code question in stackoverflow . :S

Comment: If they are an answer to your question then you shouldn't ask one but otherwise a question titled like *Detecting character code on mobile & desktop devices...* or so would be good. @DevStud

Comment: I have created a new question like you said. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328858/detecting-character-code-on-mobile-desktop-devices)

Comment: Why didn't try multiple events?

Comment: Because I never thought about it? Following the solution on your newly asked question, this should be [a working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayONJd). @DevStud

Comment: yes that fixed the problem. Working all devices now.

Comment: In the future, you may want to ask about tricky problems ASAP.

Comment: what do you mean dear. Are you thinking there are problem?

Comment: No, I just mean you should ask early whenever you failed.

Comment: thank you dear. So your help is best for me thank you so much about it. Can i ask you a question if i have some other next time? Also you teach me something in your answer thanks about it also. It looks like eveyrhing works now. You earn 150 bounthry from me congract.

Comment: No problem, I'm a problem solving freak. Feel free to ask whatever and whenever you want.

Comment: Hi dear. I have a question about copy paste think. How to disable copy paste word in tag area. For example if you copy this code `tocharcodex(";") ` and paste it from contenteditable div it shows like this `#tocharcodex(";")` but i am not allowing `(";)` characters.

Comment: You can prevent pasting by listening to paste event `document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('paste', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); });` @DevStud

Comment: Hi Dear i hope you can help me! Your code still working fine but there is one bug, it is giving me error  from `var forbiddenCharactersX = new Set([` the error  is `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set` can you help me here please ?

Answer (score 13):

I made nearly perfect solution for you. [Check it out on Codepen!](http://codepen.io/weary_adventurer/pen/rmVZdX)

Complete code:

```
var input;

function diez(event){
   var s = event.target.selectionStart;
   var e = event.target.selectionEnd;
   var v = event.target.value;
   var c = v.length;
       v = v.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/ig, ""); // line 8
   var a = v.split(" ");
   var b = [];

   /* Remove this if-block if you want undeletable diez */
   if(v == ""){
      event.target.value = v;
      return;
   }
   /* --- */

   for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      var token = a[i];
      if(i == 0) b.push("#" + token);
      else if(i > 0){
         var previous = a[i-1];
         if(previous.toLowerCase() != token.toLowerCase() && token != "")
            b.push("#" + token);
         else if (token == "")
            b.push(token);
      }
   }

   b = b.join(" ");
   c = b.length - c;
   event.target.value = b;
   event.target.selectionStart = s + c;
   event.target.selectionEnd = e + c;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   input = document.getElementById("text");
   input.addEventListener("keyup", diez, true);
});
```

- Uses jQuery only for document ready event.
- Keeps user selection and cursor position.
- Vanilla Javascript code.
- Replaced hacky content-editable div with a proper `<input>`.
- Works on keypress, not on space press.

---

**UPDATE**

- You can no longer type special characters: anything, except letters a-z, 0-9 and whitespace. You can add whitelisted characters on line 8 (e.g russian, turkish)
- Tokens that look alike are rejected.

Comment: Your response allows for special characters like `_-?*\/()=&%+^#'<|>.,;!` .  And also your code need to delete duplicated words. When user write #abc and #aBc then #aBc should be automatically delete. But thanks for your effort.

Comment: @DevStud Remove all special characters at the start of the function `v = v.replace(...);`

Comment: @DevStud Remove duplicate tags in the else condition of `if(previous.toLowerCase() != ...`

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the code which replaces the spaces with dashes to this:

```
   $("body").on("keyup", "#text", function() {
      $("#ad_text").html($(this).html().replace(/\s/g,"-"));
      go();
   });
```

That will update your #ad_text with spaces replaced by dashes. From there, changing to " #" should be pretty straightforward.

Your original code was calling `.replace` on the return jQuery item, not the `.html`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but your answer adding also empty space like `# # # # # # #`

Comment: A fair point. I think the question now becomes a regex question.

Comment: `var t = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, '-');` Turns out using the `.html()` gives you `&nbsp;` characters which aren't spaces.

Answer (score 3):

To get "#Hi #bro #how #are #you?", you can do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("keyup", "#text", function(e) {
      // Add space after press return
      if(e.keyCode == 13) { 
         $(this).text($(this).text()+' ');
      }
      // Format div content after press space or return
      if(e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 13) {
          var content =  $(this).text();
          // Format content
          content = '#' + content.replace(/#+/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' #');
          // Set content
          $(this).html(content);
          // Put cursor to the end of div
          cursorManager.setEndOfContenteditable(this);
      }
   });
});
```

You will find cursorManager.setEndOfContenteditable() as the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity/19588665#19588665)

1) To detect duplicates, you have to transform content variable into an array with the method split(), check for duplicates in this array and then use the method join() to transform array in string.

2) To dont allow _-?*/()=&%+^#'<|>.,;! you can write a function to delete these caracters and call it each time a key is pressed. Just add your function at the top of keyup event function.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple Javascript function to do the functionality;

```
function addDiszTag(str){
        //  var str = "Hi bro how are you?"
        str = str.split(' ');

        //Output will be turned to be ["Hi", "bro", "how", "are", "you?"]
        var transformedArr = [];
        str.forEach(function(ele){transformedArr.push("#"+ele) })

        // ["#Hi", "#bro", "#how", "#are", "#you?"]

        return transformedArr.join(' '); 

       //It will return "#Hi #bro #how #are #you?"

    }
```

Please add validation for checking duplicate :-)
Hope it helped

Answer (score 3):

Since JS isn't too Unicode aware, you can use an equivalent UTF-16 ranges
that correspond to the `\p{alnum}` property.

I recommend pre-compiling this to reside in a global somewhere.

This regex will just match a leading whitespace (or BOS) when it is followed by
a \p{alnum} character. Then just replace with the whitespace + #.

Basically

`var Rx = /(^|\s)(?=<see below>/g;`  (where Rx is global)
`newSrc = strSrc.replace(Rx, "$1#");`

Regex // delimited

```
/(^|\s)(?=(?:[\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\u066E-\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5-\u06E6\u06EE-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07C0-\u07EA\u07F4-\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0-\u08B4\u08B6-\u08BD\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F-\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC-\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09E6-\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F-\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32-\u0A33\u0A35-\u0A36\u0A38-\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A6F\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2-\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE1\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0AF9\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F-\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32-\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C-\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99-\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E-\u0B9F\u0BA3-\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60-\u0C61\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C80\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE1\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1-\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D54-\u0D56\u0D5F-\u0D61\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32-\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81-\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87-\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA-\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2-\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F-\u1049\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065-\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u1090-\u1099\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u17E0-\u17E9\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u1884\u1887-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1A80-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1C80-\u1C88\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5-\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183-\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005-\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA69D\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AE\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA900-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E6-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5-\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABE2\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40-\uFB41\uFB43-\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]|(?:\uD800[\uDC00-\uDC0B\uDC0D-\uDC26\uDC28-\uDC3A\uDC3C-\uDC3D\uDC3F-\uDC4D\uDC50-\uDC5D\uDC80-\uDCFA\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEA0-\uDED0\uDF00-\uDF1F\uDF30-\uDF40\uDF42-\uDF49\uDF50-\uDF75\uDF80-\uDF9D\uDFA0-\uDFC3\uDFC8-\uDFCF]|\uD801[\uDC00-\uDC9D\uDCA0-\uDCA9\uDCB0-\uDCD3\uDCD8-\uDCFB\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD63\uDE00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF67]|\uD802[\uDC00-\uDC05\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC35\uDC37-\uDC38\uDC3C\uDC3F-\uDC55\uDC60-\uDC76\uDC80-\uDC9E\uDCE0-\uDCF2\uDCF4-\uDCF5\uDD00-\uDD15\uDD20-\uDD39\uDD80-\uDDB7\uDDBE-\uDDBF\uDE00\uDE10-\uDE13\uDE15-\uDE17\uDE19-\uDE33\uDE60-\uDE7C\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEC0-\uDEC7\uDEC9-\uDEE4\uDF00-\uDF35\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF72\uDF80-\uDF91]|\uD803[\uDC00-\uDC48\uDC80-\uDCB2\uDCC0-\uDCF2]|\uD804[\uDC03-\uDC37\uDC66-\uDC6F\uDC83-\uDCAF\uDCD0-\uDCE8\uDCF0-\uDCF9\uDD03-\uDD26\uDD36-\uDD3F\uDD50-\uDD72\uDD76\uDD83-\uDDB2\uDDC1-\uDDC4\uDDD0-\uDDDA\uDDDC\uDE00-\uDE11\uDE13-\uDE2B\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE88\uDE8A-\uDE8D\uDE8F-\uDE9D\uDE9F-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEDE\uDEF0-\uDEF9\uDF05-\uDF0C\uDF0F-\uDF10\uDF13-\uDF28\uDF2A-\uDF30\uDF32-\uDF33\uDF35-\uDF39\uDF3D\uDF50\uDF5D-\uDF61]|\uD805[\uDC00-\uDC34\uDC47-\uDC4A\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC80-\uDCAF\uDCC4-\uDCC5\uDCC7\uDCD0-\uDCD9\uDD80-\uDDAE\uDDD8-\uDDDB\uDE00-\uDE2F\uDE44\uDE50-\uDE59\uDE80-\uDEAA\uDEC0-\uDEC9\uDF00-\uDF19\uDF30-\uDF39]|\uD806[\uDCA0-\uDCE9\uDCFF\uDEC0-\uDEF8]|\uD807[\uDC00-\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC2E\uDC40\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC72-\uDC8F]|\uD808[\uDC00-\uDF99]|\uD809[\uDC80-\uDD43]|\uD80C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD80D[\uDC00-\uDC2E]|\uD811[\uDC00-\uDE46]|\uD81A[\uDC00-\uDE38\uDE40-\uDE5E\uDE60-\uDE69\uDED0-\uDEED\uDF00-\uDF2F\uDF40-\uDF43\uDF50-\uDF59\uDF63-\uDF77\uDF7D-\uDF8F]|\uD81B[\uDF00-\uDF44\uDF50\uDF93-\uDF9F\uDFE0]|[\uD81C-\uD820][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD821[\uDC00-\uDFEC]|\uD822[\uDC00-\uDEF2]|\uD82C[\uDC00-\uDC01]|\uD82F[\uDC00-\uDC6A\uDC70-\uDC7C\uDC80-\uDC88\uDC90-\uDC99]|\uD835[\uDC00-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC9C\uDC9E-\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5-\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD1E-\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD52-\uDEA5\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEFA\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF34\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF6E\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDFA8\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFCB\uDFCE-\uDFFF]|\uD83A[\uDC00-\uDCC4\uDD00-\uDD43\uDD50-\uDD59]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE1F\uDE21-\uDE22\uDE24\uDE27\uDE29-\uDE32\uDE34-\uDE37\uDE39\uDE3B\uDE42\uDE47\uDE49\uDE4B\uDE4D-\uDE4F\uDE51-\uDE52\uDE54\uDE57\uDE59\uDE5B\uDE5D\uDE5F\uDE61-\uDE62\uDE64\uDE67-\uDE6A\uDE6C-\uDE72\uDE74-\uDE77\uDE79-\uDE7C\uDE7E\uDE80-\uDE89\uDE8B-\uDE9B\uDEA1-\uDEA3\uDEA5-\uDEA9\uDEAB-\uDEBB]|[\uD840-\uD868][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF]|[\uD86A-\uD86C][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD86D[\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF]|\uD86E[\uDC00-\uDC1D\uDC20-\uDFFF]|[\uD86F-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD873[\uDC00-\uDEA1]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1D])))/g
```

Regex raw expanded

```
 ( ^ | \s )                    # (1)
 (?=                           # \p{alnum}
      (?:
           [\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\u066E-\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5-\u06E6\u06EE-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07C0-\u07EA\u07F4-\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0-\u08B4\u08B6-\u08BD\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F-\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC-\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09E6-\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F-\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32-\u0A33\u0A35-\u0A36\u0A38-\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A6F\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2-\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE1\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0AF9\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F-\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32-\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C-\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99-\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E-\u0B9F\u0BA3-\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60-\u0C61\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C80\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE1\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1-\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D54-\u0D56\u0D5F-\u0D61\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32-\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81-\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87-\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA-\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2-\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F-\u1049\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065-\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u1090-\u1099\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u17E0-\u17E9\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u1884\u1887-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1A80-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1C80-\u1C88\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5-\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183-\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005-\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA69D\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AE\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA900-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E6-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5-\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABE2\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40-\uFB41\uFB43-\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC] 
        |  
           (?:
                \uD800 [\uDC00-\uDC0B\uDC0D-\uDC26\uDC28-\uDC3A\uDC3C-\uDC3D\uDC3F-\uDC4D\uDC50-\uDC5D\uDC80-\uDCFA\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEA0-\uDED0\uDF00-\uDF1F\uDF30-\uDF40\uDF42-\uDF49\uDF50-\uDF75\uDF80-\uDF9D\uDFA0-\uDFC3\uDFC8-\uDFCF] 
             |  \uD801 [\uDC00-\uDC9D\uDCA0-\uDCA9\uDCB0-\uDCD3\uDCD8-\uDCFB\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD63\uDE00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF67] 
             |  \uD802 [\uDC00-\uDC05\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC35\uDC37-\uDC38\uDC3C\uDC3F-\uDC55\uDC60-\uDC76\uDC80-\uDC9E\uDCE0-\uDCF2\uDCF4-\uDCF5\uDD00-\uDD15\uDD20-\uDD39\uDD80-\uDDB7\uDDBE-\uDDBF\uDE00\uDE10-\uDE13\uDE15-\uDE17\uDE19-\uDE33\uDE60-\uDE7C\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEC0-\uDEC7\uDEC9-\uDEE4\uDF00-\uDF35\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF72\uDF80-\uDF91] 
             |  \uD803 [\uDC00-\uDC48\uDC80-\uDCB2\uDCC0-\uDCF2] 
             |  \uD804 [\uDC03-\uDC37\uDC66-\uDC6F\uDC83-\uDCAF\uDCD0-\uDCE8\uDCF0-\uDCF9\uDD03-\uDD26\uDD36-\uDD3F\uDD50-\uDD72\uDD76\uDD83-\uDDB2\uDDC1-\uDDC4\uDDD0-\uDDDA\uDDDC\uDE00-\uDE11\uDE13-\uDE2B\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE88\uDE8A-\uDE8D\uDE8F-\uDE9D\uDE9F-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEDE\uDEF0-\uDEF9\uDF05-\uDF0C\uDF0F-\uDF10\uDF13-\uDF28\uDF2A-\uDF30\uDF32-\uDF33\uDF35-\uDF39\uDF3D\uDF50\uDF5D-\uDF61] 
             |  \uD805 [\uDC00-\uDC34\uDC47-\uDC4A\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC80-\uDCAF\uDCC4-\uDCC5\uDCC7\uDCD0-\uDCD9\uDD80-\uDDAE\uDDD8-\uDDDB\uDE00-\uDE2F\uDE44\uDE50-\uDE59\uDE80-\uDEAA\uDEC0-\uDEC9\uDF00-\uDF19\uDF30-\uDF39] 
             |  \uD806 [\uDCA0-\uDCE9\uDCFF\uDEC0-\uDEF8] 
             |  \uD807 [\uDC00-\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC2E\uDC40\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC72-\uDC8F] 
             |  \uD808 [\uDC00-\uDF99] 
             |  \uD809 [\uDC80-\uDD43] 
             |  \uD80C [\uDC00-\uDFFF] 
             |  \uD80D [\uDC00-\uDC2E] 
             |  \uD811 [\uDC00-\uDE46] 
             |  \uD81A [\uDC00-\uDE38\uDE40-\uDE5E\uDE60-\uDE69\uDED0-\uDEED\uDF00-\uDF2F\uDF40-\uDF43\uDF50-\uDF59\uDF63-\uDF77\uDF7D-\uDF8F] 
             |  \uD81B [\uDF00-\uDF44\uDF50\uDF93-\uDF9F\uDFE0] 
             |  [\uD81C-\uD820] [\uDC00-\uDFFF] 
             |  \uD821 [\uDC00-\uDFEC] 
             |  \uD822 [\uDC00-\uDEF2] 
             |  \uD82C [\uDC00-\uDC01] 
             |  \uD82F [\uDC00-\uDC6A\uDC70-\uDC7C\uDC80-\uDC88\uDC90-\uDC99] 
             |  \uD835 [\uDC00-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC9C\uDC9E-\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5-\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD1E-\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD52-\uDEA5\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEFA\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF34\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF6E\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDFA8\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFCB\uDFCE-\uDFFF] 
             |  \uD83A [\uDC00-\uDCC4\uDD00-\uDD43\uDD50-\uDD59] 
             |  \uD83B [\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE1F\uDE21-\uDE22\uDE24\uDE27\uDE29-\uDE32\uDE34-\uDE37\uDE39\uDE3B\uDE42\uDE47\uDE49\uDE4B\uDE4D-\uDE4F\uDE51-\uDE52\uDE54\uDE57\uDE59\uDE5B\uDE5D\uDE5F\uDE61-\uDE62\uDE64\uDE67-\uDE6A\uDE6C-\uDE72\uDE74-\uDE77\uDE79-\uDE7C\uDE7E\uDE80-\uDE89\uDE8B-\uDE9B\uDEA1-\uDEA3\uDEA5-\uDEA9\uDEAB-\uDEBB] 
             |  [\uD840-\uD868] [\uDC00-\uDFFF] 
             |  \uD869 [\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF] 
             |  [\uD86A-\uD86C] [\uDC00-\uDFFF] 
             |  \uD86D [\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF] 
             |  \uD86E [\uDC00-\uDC1D\uDC20-\uDFFF] 
             |  [\uD86F-\uD872] [\uDC00-\uDFFF] 
             |  \uD873 [\uDC00-\uDEA1] 
             |  \uD87E [\uDC00-\uDE1D] 
           )
      )
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. So do you have any working example like revo answer ?

Comment: @DevStud - Not really a JS code guru. I was looking at your function that does all the replacements, but I'm using IE11 and that snippet doesn't work on my browser. I also tried your codepen demo but that didn't work either. I actually need a code framework that already works just to change/modify the regexes. Got one ?

Comment: revo used [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) . I also found your solution before. It gives me some problem. Like my question problem.

Comment: @DevStud - I'm not sure I've posted this solution before. As for it's viability, it works just fine in JS. You can see it here https://regex101.com/r/T8RhDh/1

Comment: character problem is solved. Just one problem staying here. Number 3

Answer (score -2):

I think this will do.

> IMPORTANT NOTICE : I do not know why especially you wanted space or enter hit. But when you do that, there becomes some issues. For example when someone changes mind and deletes the input with backspace, the output hash tags remain same, as the event never gets triggered because no spacebar is hit. That is why i did this with `keyup` function.

```js
    $("body").on("keypress", "#text", function(e) {
        if (e.which > 33 && e.which < 48 || e.which > 57 && e.which < 65 || e.which > 90 && e.which < 96 || e.keyCode === 13)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $("body").on("keyup", "#text", function(e) {
        var array = new Array();
        var diez = new Array();

        temparray = $('.addiez').html().split(" ");
        l = temparray.length;
        temparray[l-1] = temparray[l-1].replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'');

        $.each(temparray, function(i, el){
            el = el.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'');
            el = el.toLowerCase();
            if($.inArray(el, array) === -1) array.push(el);
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            diez[i] = "#" + array[i] + " ";
        }
        $("#ad_text").html(diez);
    });
```

```css
  .container {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:600px;
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:10px;
   margin:0px auto;
   margin-top:50px;
}
* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.addiez {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:30px;
   border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
   outline:none;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.addiez::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
   color: rgb(0, 0, 1);
}
.addiez[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before  {
      content:attr(placeholder);
      color: #444;
    }

.note {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:30px;
   font-weight:300;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   line-height:1.8rem;
   font-size:13px;
}
.ad_text {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:10px 30px;
   overflow:hidden;
   font-weight:300;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   line-height:1.8rem;
   font-size:13px;
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="addiez" contenteditable="true" id="text" placeholder="Write something with space"></div>
   <div class="ad_text" id="ad_text"></div>
   
   <div class="note">For example: When you write like: Hi bro how are you? Then jquery should change this text like this:
   #Hi #bro #how #are #you? I meant when user pressed space or pressed enter then add diez tag before the text like my exapmle.</div>
</div>
```

> I added `text-transform: capitalize;` cause i like it :) But you can disable of course.

Comment: I don't need to show diez tags from the `.ad_text` div. When user write abc then diez tag will automatically added before the text like `#abc` in `class="addiez"` or `id="text"`   . Your code didn't do it. 

Someone gives you mines vote because of you didn't understand my question. Please check the @Weary-Adventurer's answer. He gives me correct answer.