# Safari ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I am getting Safari `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set` error from safari browser. I have checked other browsers but I didn't get any this error all codes working fine for me.

Is anyone can help me here what is wrong here and what is the solution to work my code from all browsers?

Full **[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvgqPJ)**

Problem Line

```
 var charactersX = new Set([
      0,
      32, // space
      13 // enter
      // add other punctuation symbols or keys
   ]);
  // Convert characters to charCode
   function toCharCodeX(char) {
      return char.charCodeAt(0);
   }

   var forbiddenCharactersX = new Set([
      toCharCodeX("_"),
      toCharCodeX("-"),
      toCharCodeX("?"),
      toCharCodeX("*"),
      toCharCodeX("\\"),
      toCharCodeX("/"),
      toCharCodeX("("),
      toCharCodeX(")"),
      toCharCodeX("="),
      toCharCodeX("&"),
      toCharCodeX("%"),
      toCharCodeX("+"),
      toCharCodeX("^"),
      toCharCodeX("#"),
      toCharCodeX("'"),
      toCharCodeX("<"),
      toCharCodeX("|"),
      toCharCodeX(">"),
      toCharCodeX("."),
      toCharCodeX(","),
      toCharCodeX(";")
   ]);
```

Comment: What version of Safari are you using? It's been more or less [supported since version 7.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @RobM. Hmm, i see it. So do you have any idea for any solution to work all browsers like desktop and mobile devices?

Comment: @RobM. If you have any idea you can answer from this bounty [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351621/check-pressed-space-then-add-diez-tag-using-jquery-with-multi-language)

Comment: Use an array instead...

Comment: you can try this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript

Comment: Not needed @Sourav . For what he does, an array is perfectly fine. No need for anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrays instead

```
var charactersX = [
  0,
  32, // space
  13 // enter
  // add other punctuation symbols or keys
];
```

and replace the `.has()`, e.g. here:

```
if (charactersX.has(code))
```

with

```
if (charactersX.indexOf(code) > -1)
```

and

```
if (forbiddenCharactersX.has(code))
```

with `indexOf > -1` too...

Comment: your code is working fine. Thanks for it. But i have a question from you if you have a time please answer me. I have used CharcodeAt(0); in demo on line 76, to work my code on mobile devices. But it is not working on mobile. What is the problem here? You can check it my question [DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/RZwrzQ)

Comment: You have charCodeAt(0) in your pen, this shouldn't be a problem on mobile.  If you have further errors, feel free to ask a new question and include the details @DevStud

Comment: I have included a bounty question from here about my comment question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351621/check-pressed-space-then-add-diez-tag-using-jquery-with-multi-language)